# How to create a update patch link Joomla update from SVN

Tags: php, svn, patch

I saw that in Joomla every time they release a new update. it only contain the file that have been change from the last release with the same directory structure.
So I have a SVN server. And I have modified something in the SVN and now I want to create the update path like Joomla how can I do that?

Thanks, for Your Answer!!!

Comment: Could you post a sample output that you want to get?

Comment: for example, I have 3 folder dir1, dir2 and dir3 in the root of SVN, and in dir1 I have 2 file file1 and file2, dir2 and dir3 is empty. So now I'm working on the working copy and have add file3 in dir2 and also have modify file1. So now I want to create directory that exactly like the old one but only contain the file have modify and added. not include the file and folder that is doesn't modify. in this example the create directory will be dir1 and dir2 in dir1 will have file1 and in dir2 will have file3. that's all. So I can copy this directory to a new server or something to update code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TortoiseSVN in Windows you can follow these steps (copy&pasted from [this source](http://verysimple.com/2007/09/06/using-tortoisesvn-to-export-only-newmodified-files)):

1. Using TortoiseSVN, right-click on your working folder and select “Show Log” from the TortoiseSVN menu.
2. Click the revision that was last published (#85 in this example)
3. Ctrl+Click the HEAD revision (or whatever revision you want to release ie #178) so that both the old and the new revisions are highlighted.
4. Right-click on either of the highlighted revisions and select “Compare revisions.”  This will open a dialog window that lists all new/modified files.
5. Select all files from this list (Ctrl+a) then right-click on the highlighted files and select “Export selection to…”

For use in Linux I have found a script creating the whole directory structure based on the output of this line:

```
svn diff -r <revision_number>:HEAD --summarize <working_directory>
```

The script can be found [here](http://www.falconnet.fr/Subversion-export-des-fichiers.html).